# Aurelia Fetch Client - Unsupported Media Type - .NET Core WebAPI

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, aurelia, aurelia-fetch-client

When I try to post two parameters as JSON using Aurelia Fetch Client to a .NET Core WebAPI I get: `415 (Unsupported Media Type)`

**ApplicationController**

```
[HttpPost("getapplications")]
public ApplicationViewModel GetApplications([FromBody] ApplicationSearchModel model)
{
    var applications = _applicationService.GetApplications().ToList();

    return new ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        Applications = applications
    };
}

public class ApplicationSearchModel
{
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }

    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
}
```

**application.js**

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

@inject(HttpClient)

export class Application {
  constructor(httpClient) {
    this.applications = [];

    this.httpClient = httpClient;
  }

  getApplications() {
    this.httpClient.fetch("http://localhost:9001/api/application/getapplications", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        From: '2017-02-18',
        To: '2017-02-18'
      }),
        headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" //Tried without headers aswell
      }
    });
  }

  activate(params) {
    this.getApplications();
  }
}
```

If I remove `[FromBody]` it posts but the properties inside my `ApplicationSearchModel` is null.

When I posted with Postman using the following settings:

Url:

```
http://localhost:9001/api/application/getapplications
```

Body:

```
{
    "from": "2017-02-18",
    "to": "2017-02-18"
}
```

Header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Everything worked and my properties inside `ApplicationSearchModel` was not null.

When I look at the requests that Aurelia Fetch Client generate It seems like the Content-Type header is missing..

**Edit**

Request Headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:9001
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Is the CORS enabled?

Comment: No, but its not a cross-domain request

Comment: The reason of `415 (Unsupported Media Type)` is exactly what you have mentioned: _It seems like the Content-Type header is missing_.

Comment: I have tried every possible way to add content-type but it keeps ignoring everything i do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

..It was actually a CORS problem.

I added cors settings in Startup.cs to allow all origins:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //CORS---------
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
    });

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    services.AddMvc();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //CORS---------
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    loggerFactory.AddConsole();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseMvc();

    app.UseDefaultFiles();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    // app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    // {
    //     FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    //     Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "src")),
    //     RequestPath = new PathString("/src")
    // });
}
```

And everything worked..

My Aurelia application is hosted on **port:9000** and my .NET app is hosted on **port:90001**. The idea is to serve static pages from my .NET app once the app is published but now in development I use **port:9000** because of the BrowserSync provided by Aurelia, (CORS will not be an issue when published, but it is now when using port:9000 locally).

### Is it possible to use port:9000 locally and NOT enable CORS?

**Edit:**

CORS enabled on localhost only:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:9000")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials();
});
```

Comment: http://abusanad.net/2018/09/17/fetch-data-using-javascript-from-asp-net-core-localhost/

Answer (score 0):

Your headers is not setup properly.

It should be

```
{
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" 
}
```

Instead of

```
{
    "content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}
```

Comment: Hi, was actually a typo when I edited my question. Does not solve my problem